# How to convert text file into csv

Tags: c#, csv

I have an input file with fixed columns lengths and I need the file converted to csv.

The current code transforms it into csv but the columns are offset based on varying lengths of whitespace.

How do I remove the extra commas to make the number of columns uniform?

C#, Visual Studio & CSV

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

namespace write_csv
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string csvfilePath = @"C:\Users\ai_hacker\Desktop\output.csv";
            string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\ai_hacker\Desktop\orsc1827.ot2");

            foreach (string line in lines)
            {
                var parts = line.Split(' ');
                string csvLine = string.Join(',', parts);
                Console.WriteLine(csvLine);

                File.AppendAllText(csvfilePath, csvLine + Environment.NewLine);
            }


        }
    }
}
```

Input:

```
439790                6806991   4700       NORTH AMERICAN 04/18/19  08161895  P90947L6 - O076GG7F
91921221              6835746   1385       GALLAGHER POWER04/18/19  09024922  P90948G0 - O076GHAR
```

current output:

```
439790,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,6806991,,,4700,,,,,,,NORTH,AMERICAN,04/18/19,,08161895,,P90947L6,-,O076GG7F
91921221,,,,,,,,,,,,,,6835746,,,1385,,,,,,,GALLAGHER,POWER04/18/19,,09024922,,P90948G0,-,O076GHAR
```

Need the columns to line up:

```
439790,6806991,4700,NORTH,AMERICAN,04/18/19,08161895,P90947L6,-,O076GG7F
91921221,6835746,1385,GALLAGHER,POWER04/18/19,09024922,P90948G0,-,O076GHAR
```

Comment: Can you add a sample of your input data and what do you expect as output?

Comment: Looks like file already has commas so it is csv.  Is this input or output? column1data,column2data,ect

Comment: split values with some separator ('white space' in your case) from `ot2` file and then join with commas

Comment: the input is space separated in txt, need it csv

Comment: Do not update the question with the answers. At the least make an extra section at the bottom.

Comment: "Both provided an output in the console ..." - no, the first fragment does _not_ write to the console at all. You are testing/looking the wrong way. Or runing an old copy of the program.

Comment: Im running it in Visual Studio, I hit Run and the console is pulling up all the data

Comment: I created a new project and that seemed to do the trick. Its printing out with the commas now. the only difference i see in the code is this line : static void Main(string[] args)

Comment: 2 problems with the output: 1. its all on 1 line and 2. the columns dont line up, some have too many commas between columns

Comment: 0k, reformatted the input. Your input now looks more like tab-separated or fixed-width. Do you know which one?

Comment: fixed width; OUT-INV-NBR 1
OUT-PO-NBR 23
OUT-VENDOR-NBR 33
OUT-VENDOR-NAME 44
OUT-DATE 59
OUT-TIME 69
OUT-PROCESSQ 79
OUT-OUTPUTQ 90

Comment: Your input and output samples are not about the same data. Splitting on spaces is not going to work. Add this to your question or ask a new one.

Comment: The difference in the input and output is bc the script is not appending the data, its overwriting it all on 1 line, im only seeing the last 2 results

Comment: I removed 'File.WriteAllText(csvfilePath, csvLine);' and that fixed it; now all i need is to inset a line break after each line, so I get rows of data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This job could be done in a single line without an explicit loop with

```
string csvfilePath = @"C:\Users\Desktop\ooutput.csv";
string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Desktop\orsc1827.ot2");
var result = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, 
                    lines.Select(x => x.Split(' '))
                         .Select(x => string.Join(",", x)));
File.WriteAllText(csvfilePath, result);
```

With a sample input of

```
string input = @"
     1846223 6833581-1 75522 ADMC 04/17/19 09283609 P9093CC8 - O076FDE4
     1846201 6833581-1 75522 ADMC 04/17/19 09284581 P9093CC4 - O076FDE9";
```

I got this output in the result string

```
1846223,6833581-1,75522,ADMC,04/17/19,09283609,P9093CC8,-,O076FDE4
1846201,6833581-1,75522,ADMC,04/17/19,09284581,P9093CC4,-,O076FDE9
```

And if you want to keep the last two substrings together then you can add

```
var result = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, 
              lines.Select(x => x.Replace(" - ", "-")
                  .Split(' ')).Select(x => string.Join(",", x)));
```

If you had more than one space between data, you could remove the extra spaces with this change

```
var result = string.Join(Environment.NewLine,
          lines.Select(x => x.Replace(" - ", "-")
               .Split(new char[] { ' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
               .Select(x => string.Join(",", x)));
```

Comment: Thank you, Im still not seeing the commas in the output

Comment: I have tested with a sample input and I get the comma as expected. Something should be different then

Comment: Error: string[] does not contain a definition for 'Select'

Comment: You need to add _using Linq;_ at the top of your .cs file

Comment: It ran but the csv file did not get created

Comment: I am unsure what could be the problem. I think you should start your debugger and check what is the content of the variable _result_ after this code. Also, do you have some try/catch around this code? Do you get any exception while trying to save to disk?

Comment: Your code is the only thing in there. short and sweet, but the file never created. Is there some sort of permissions or library needed?

Comment: The output path seems to be wrong. There is no Desktop folder inside a C:\users folder. Are you missing a part of the path to your own desktop folder? IE _C:\users\yourusername\desktop_

Comment: How do i get rid of the extra commas between columns? The  columns dont line up

Comment: Added a fix for extra spaces

Answer (score 4):

> the input is space separated in txt, need it csv

```
foreach (string line in lines)
{
    var parts = line.Split(' ');
    string csvLine = string.Join(',', parts);
    Console.WriteLine(csvLine);
}
```

This is a quick fix. For 'official' csv you would need to consider putting `"` around text fields, and therefore disinguish text and numbers.

Comment: I get an error "Cannot assign 'line' because it is a 'foreach iteration variable'

Comment: @user9794893 - yes, edited. You need an extra string.

Comment: Thank you, the output in the cmd console does not show the commas. I alo need it to print into a csv file

Comment: "does not show the commas" is unclear and unlikely. Check the WriteLine, does it print the right string?

Comment: How do I check the WriteLine?

Comment: By looking  at it. Does it say `(line)` or `(csvLine)` ?

Comment: Im looking at the printed results in the command console. The commas are not showing up. Its printing exactly the way it came in

Comment: Add a section to your questin (leave the current text) and add the _exact_ code that converts and prints. Copy/Pastre the code, do not retype it.

Comment: I updated the code, how do I remove all the extra white spaces between columns?

Answer (score 1):

Try this one if you are not sure about the number of spaces between values in a row.

```
RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.None;
Regex regex = new Regex("[ ]{2,}", options);     

string csvline;
foreach (string line in lines)
{
    csvline = regex.Replace(line, ",");
    Console.WriteLine(csvline);
}
```

If you are sure you only have one, you can just

```
string csvline;
foreach (string csvline in lines){
        csvline = line.Replace(' ', ',');
        Console.WriteLine(csvline);
}
```

Comment: I get an error "Cannot assign 'line' because it is a 'foreach iteration variable'

Comment: ah, sorry. You cannot assign to variables of the iteration. Changed it to csvline

Comment: I used the first one, and is printing in the cmd console but i dont see the commas

Comment: How do i get rid of the extra commas between columns? The columns dont line up

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell exactly what you're asking for here, so my answer is going to be pretty vague.

For a delimited file, you'll be delimiting values of some sort, so I'm going to have to make some assumptions about what those values are.   The [String.Join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=netframework-4.8) function is probably what you're looking for there.   It produces a string output which is the product of an array of objects joined with the specified separator.  (e.g. [1,2,3] => "1,2,3")

As far as writing the ouput to a file, the function you need is similar to what you used to read the file.   The File object has a [WriteAllText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealltext?view=netframework-4.8) function which will produce a text file containing the given text (as a string), or [File.WriteAllLines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealllines?view=netframework-4.8) will have a similar result, but with an array of strings.